# Selecting polygons which contain majority of area from intersected layer by polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, area, select-by-attribute, intersect

I have two polygons layers (a squares grid (blue in image) and a rectangles grid (green in image)). Because the different polygon sizes, different squares overlap with a single rectangle. I need to find the square with the highest overlapping area for each rectangle, so at the end, I could assign each square to one rectangle. Somehow, I would like to filter just the rectangles with squares assigned after applying this rule. Notice that two squares could be assigned to the same rectangle.

Just to have in mind: the squares don´t have the same area, as in the borders it may be an incomplete square (see image), but still need to know in which rectangle fall the majority of its area.

[image]

I am using QGIS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Plugin: Select Within](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SelectWithin/) which can help you to select the polygons where their centroids are located within the other polygon. It is same as select by location with additional option to have the centroids located completely within the polygon of other layer.

You can apply the selection on the whole polygon layer or only on selected polygons.

[image]